Issues with filtering by lastModifiedDate for SharePoint with GraphApi
It is already a week and I can't still find a way to get some documents from my SharePoint and be able to filter by lastModifiedDate.
I am working on an application for getting documents from SharePoint using GraphAPI. Given a root folder from SharePoint, I want to list all documents that where modified since a arbitrary date.
For example in my "Shared Documents" drive, I have a folder "TestSharePoint" and some files there, that I want to retrieve with filter by lastModifiedDate.
I try using something like this https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/root/search/queryI am getting "General exception while processing". Even if I have like a basic query just for a string, like, the below one, it still returns exception.
{

  "requests": [

    {

      "entityTypes": [

        "driveItem"

      ],

      "query": {

        "queryString": "contoso"

      }

      ]

    }

  ]

}

For me, the above call seems more logical, because I can have many tenants each with different sites/drives, and like this I can point to the exact site and drive.
If I use this call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query with body, I am getting exception "SearchRequest Invalid (Region is required when request with application permission.)"
{

  "region": "GBR",

  "requests": [

    {

      "entityTypes": [

        "driveItem"

      ],

      "query": {

        "queryString": "path:\"https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{someSites}/Shared%20Documents/\" AND LastModifiedDateTime > 2024-07-16T00:00:00Z"

      }

    }

  ]

}

But, I am am logged into the the developer.microsoft.com, into Graph explorer, requests with query, without specify the region, works fine, but I don't know if I am missing some permissions or what happens.
My permissions are Microsoft Graph Files.Read.All, Sites.Selected, User.Read
I tried different variations and examples but could not make it work, maybe I am missing permissions but I am not sure what I am missing. Also maybe the api is not implemented.

I use this API to filter the document library by date:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime lt 2024-07-16T00:00:00Z

Reference: Use the $filter query parameter
Here are my results:

To get the site ID use:
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/<site-url>/_api/web/id

To get the drive id:
First, run this API and get id value.
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<tenant>.sharepoint.com:/sites/<siteName>


Second, Run this api to get drive id.
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<The id value you got earlier>/drives



Thanks for the response, but the issue is that this api for filtering, will filter the whole drive, I want to filter a specific root folder from the drive
